# Not Rendering images in react-natives flatlist if using extern uri

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I just migrated my ListView to the faster FlatList and currently got the issue that images with an external uri aren't rendered. If I'm using require('localUri') everything works fine.

1) The URL is https
2) I see that the grey rectangles (style of the image) are rendered
3) Using a local image with require(localImagePath) is working
4) The imageUrlThumb is valid if I'm requesting on the browser

```
 <FlatList
data={this.props.items}
keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
numColumns={3}
renderItem={rowData => {
    return (
        <Image
            style={{
                width: size,
                height: size,
                margin: 2,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "#eee"
            }}
            source={{ uri: rowData.imageUrlThumb, cache: "force-cache" }}
            resizeMode="contain"
        />
    );
}}
/>;
```

Would be nice if anyone could help me with this.

Best regards
Kay

Environment:
  OS:  macOS High Sierra 10.13
  Node:  6.11.0
  Yarn:  1.2.1
  npm:  5.4.2
  Watchman:  4.9.0

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.0.0-beta.5 => 16.0.0-beta.5
  react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-22.0.1.tar.gz => https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-22.0.1.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
source={{uri: rowData.imageUrlThumb, cache: 'force-cache'}}
```

`rowData.imageUrlThumb` is undefined.

You have a syntax error in `renderItem`.

According to the FlatList data structure, you either have to call `rowData.item` within the rendering or use curly braces in `renderItem={({item}) => {`, to denote that you're going to use the `item` in the `rowData` object. That is, either use `(rowData) => rowData.item` or use `({item}) => item`.

Comment: AH! Thanks! FastList has a new data structure in their iterating items. your answer is not fully right. Its okay that im using the rowData without the curly brackets but then I have to call rowData.item within the rendering. If I only want to geht the item, I have to use either (rowData) => rowData.item or ({item}) => item. :) so please update your answer, then i can mark is positive. thanks so much

Comment: @KayEs just updated my answer. Check if it is correct now. :)